# Clojure Cursive noob load into repl and cannot run hello world

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, cursive

Exploring Clojure - I am working through *Clojure For The Brave And True*. I created the hello world (in this case, I'm a little teapot). I can run it from lein repl just as the book suggests.

The author of the book appears to be a big emacs fan. I am comfortable with **Intellij Idea**, so installed the **Cursive** plugin. I then:

1. Set up a repl "runner" as shown on the Cursive site.
2. Tried loading the hello world into the repl. It appears to have done
   so.

Now what? I presumed after loading the contents of the editor, I could run it, but have not figured out how. Obviously, this is a very noob question.

The code in my editor follows.

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "I'm a little teapot!")
)
```

The repl window is divided into two panes. The upper pain shows it is connected to the local nREPL server. Then, after loading it states:

```
Loading src/clojure_noob/core.clj... done
```

In the lower pane, per comments, I tried two variations of run, both of which failed miserable as you can see below (it didn't surprise me the second failed for it was calling out *run*, not the function).

```
run -main
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: run in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init2302589649746976452.clj:1:4481) 
=> #object[clojure_noob.core$_main 0x24d21d67 "clojure_noob.core$_main@24d21d67"]
run clojure-noob.core/-main
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: run in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init2302589649746976452.clj:1:4481) 
=> #object[clojure_noob.core$_main 0x24d21d67 "clojure_noob.core$_main@24d21d67"]
```

---

***ANSWER***
Thanks to comments from @Carcigenicate, I was able to figure out what to do. The answer is:

1. Enter (clojure-noob.core/-main) into the lower pane
2. Position cursor to the right of the closing paren
3. Press enter.

This resulted in the following:

```
(clojure-noob.core/-main)
I'm a little teapot!
=> nil
```

Told you it was a noob question!

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but for an IDE, I highly recommend IntelliJ + Cursive. It's fantastic, and free. Been using the combo for over a year now.

Comment: And run `-main` manually after it loads. The main won't necessarily be run automatically.

Comment: I thought it was clear from my comments that I am running Cursive. :-( I am editing my question to show the results as I understand you to mean. but, maybe i am doing something else wrong.

Comment: You're using Cursive, but it's integration with emacs may be poor. I just thought I'd suggest IntelliJ as I have had great experiences with it.

Comment: And in the REPL, did you run `(-main)`?

Comment: Emacs is not in the picture at all. I was just stating that the book author strongly suggested using emacs - had a whole chapter on it, in fact. I am using Intellij Idea with the Cursive plugin. I do know the difference. I am a noob to Clojure and the Cursive plugin - but not to development.

Comment: in the lower pane, I have entered (-main) and pressed enter. nothing happens. I assume since (I can enter (+ 1 2) and get 3, that this is the correct place to launch a run of main. likewise, entering (clojure-noob.core/-main) does nothing.

Comment: never mind! i got it! I did enter (clojure-noob.core/-main), however my cursor was inside the parens when i pressed enter. moving to the right of the last paren did give me the correct results. Thanks @Carcigenicate

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. And sorry, I was a little distracted when I was commenting

Comment: Note, you shouldn't have to namespace-qualify the call to - main. You can switch the namespace to the current file so that that's not necessary. In the settings, look up the key commands to switch the REPL namespace and load a file into the REPL. I have those bound to ctrl+shift+m and ctrl+shift+l since I use them so frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This will be much easier in the next version of Cursive - the EAP will hopefully be out later this week or next week. You'll have the IntelliJ-standard ways of running `-main` functions more easily accessible:
[image]

Of course, the Clojure Way is to use the REPL as you're discovering, so continuing to explore that way of programming is definitely to be encouraged!